# rails deployment fails on asset precompilation due to npm/pyton issue

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, npm, webpacker

In the process of deploying to a Ubuntu 20.04 server

```
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 yarn install v1.22.19
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
      01 warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 error /home/deploy/mainapp/releases/20230403051422/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
[...]
      01 gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
      01 gyp verb command configure []
      01 gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
      01 gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
      01 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/deploy/mainapp/shared/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
...
      01 gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
      01 gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
      01 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/deploy/mainapp/shared/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
[...]
     01 gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
      01 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/home/deploy/mainapp/shared/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
[... concluding with]
    01 gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/deploy/mainapp/shared/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
      01 gyp ERR! cwd /home/deploy/mainapp/shared/node_modules/node-sass
      01 gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
      01 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
      01 gyp ERR! not ok
```

Investigating: `/usr/bin` has two directories `python3` and `python3.8`.  Yet, the deploy seems to hunt for `python` or `python2`...

This did not occur on another deployment for the same app on a different machine, still with Ubuntu 20.04.

The intricacies of npm, python and webpack are confounding.

What needs to be done to get the asset precompilation to complete?

Comment: `node-gyp 3.8.0` requires `python 2`. it's a `node-sass` dependency. so just upgrade `node-sass` or you could install python 2, but that's a step backwards. also, python 2 and node-sass are quite obsolete. it may be worth moving to dart-sass.

Comment: Which upgrade route to follow? I have seen different references  `npm install node-sass`  vs `npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass` but those specify "install" whereas the npm package repository is not specific about upgrading...  tricky navigation.

Comment: `--unsafe-perm` if you have permission issues, like, when running as root. `npm update node-sass` to update. you might need to bump the node-sass version in `package.json`

Comment: Installing `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3 -y` did overcome some bits (processed longer and no check for "python" `gyp verb 'which' succeeded python /usr/bin/python` ... but this hangup remains:  `gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 [...] gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH` as does `yp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];` pointing sytnax error on first double-quote after 'print' . `package.json` is devoid of version mentions for node-sass.

Comment: you're still running `node-gyp 3.8.0` it doesn't work with python 3. you can always add a version in package.json, if it doesn't update, to see if there is some other dependencies that prevent update.

Comment: From my recent investigations, `node-gyp 3.8.0` is a `@rails#webacker` dependency.  Updating the gem to latest version has allowed deployment to a `development` version of the application, but not the `production` one.  both do NOT have python2 installed, but python3.8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Alex comments, `node-gyp 3.8.0` is the offending party.  why?

Using yarn tool why

```
yarn why node-gyp
yarn why node-sass
```

allows one to climb up the dependencies structure.  In this case it was `@rails#webpacker` requiring these elements.

Along the way, a number of banana peels are laid out for one's pleasure, convenience and forced learning:
• a pre-set rails application may have the gem version cast. It may be old.
• that gem may, in fact, not be in synch with the content of the `package.json` settings.
• even then, updating the gem will **not** percolate to the yarn eco-system
• one can run `yarn install`  subsequently on the origin machine & attempt deploy. Odds are development will succeed.
• oddly, development and production will **not** have identical behaviours, at least with respect to CSS (*I really never understood why CSS had to be handled like JS - as if they were conceived by the same minds*)
• a final cherry on the bananas: production would still not deploy, even though one could successfully execute `yarn install` or `RAILS_EN=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on the latest release of the production server
• the previous iteration (either or both of yarn install and asset precompilation) was required to finally allow a successful production deployment.